# Unsuspected result from String.IndexOf

Tags: c#, string

I am wondering if I have found a bug in the String.IndexOf function, or if I am doing something wrong:

My process is this:

```
// Read bytes from file
string fileContent = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
var res = GetAllOfType("LHAND_POSE", filecontent)

List<int> GetAllOfType(string tagName, string fileContent)
{
    List<int> output = new List<int>();
    var length = tagName.Length;
    var currentIndex = fileContent.IndexOf(tagName);
    while (currentIndex != -1)
    {
        output.Add(currentIndex - 2);
        currentIndex = fileContent.IndexOf(tagName, currentIndex + length);
    }
    return output;
}
```

res contains 4 values, each is the offset from the beginning of the file with 2 bytes subtracted. Value 0 and 1 is correct, but 2 and 3 has the wrong offset. Its off by one. It also works for parsing a large amount of files, but this one and a few others fail. Any idea why?

This is the file: https://gofile.io/d/11SFM4

The file content can also be found here if people dont trust the file, although I am not sure the byte data transferred correctly when copy pasting as a string:

```
      
 RHAND_POSE
                      €?
 LHAND_POSE
   _ñ>_ñ>           €? DISABLE_PERSISTENT
                 
 LHAND_POSE
   UsU?UsU?           €?    WEAPON_ON
                            
 IMPACT_POS
   RG—?RG—?      Y-Ê¼bž×?ê{[@
 LHAND_POSE
   X%@X%@           €?
 LHAND_POSE
   
Ö7?
Ö7?           €? DOCK_EQPT_RHAND
                                FACE_POSE
   Øz?Øz?           €?    FACE_POSE
   
>?
>?           €?    FACE_POSE
   vp•?vp•?           €?    FACE_POSE
   jˆ
@jˆ
@           €?  FACE_POSE
   ú÷?ú÷?           €?    FACE_POSE
   yœÚ?yœÚ?           €?    FACE_POSE
   ËÇ¿?ËÇ¿?           €?    FACE_POSE
   âa?âa?           €?
 SPLASH_ATTACK
   „š?„š?                  òQH@        QM™@  €?  ´C  –C   A   EFFECT   'z›?'z›?      ' wh_main_terrain_unit_impact_small_grass             |G@              €?ÿÿÿÿ  €?
```

Comment: This file does not seem to be UTF-8 encoded. So reading it into a string using UTF-8 encoding may lead to unpredictable results ...

Comment: I feel dumb now, changing it to ASCII worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong encoding, as comment pointed out. File is encoded in ASCII

Comment: I can not mark as answer, if a mod sees this and want to do it, feel free.

Comment: I know, but I have had moderators complain to me about it earlier :)